# how to create grouped barchat with our ggplot in r

Tags: r, bar-chart

```
Year    Balance TotalDeposits
1   18837.44    18000
2   39313.74    36000
3   61571.47    54000
4   85765.63    72000
5   112064.68   90000
6   140651.75   108000
7   171725.89   126000
8   205503.49   144000
9   242219.73   162000
10  282130.29   180000
11  325513.06   198000
```

I have matrix

I would like to create a grouped barchat where x axis takes year as categorial variable. 
And bar represents balace and total deposits for corresponding year.

please suggest basic barchat function rather than ggplot or lattice functions.

I am reading the data from .csv file.

What I have tried so far

```
d <- read.table(text="Year  Balance TotalDeposits
1   18837.44    18000
2   39313.74    36000
3   61571.47    54000
4   85765.63    72000
5   112064.68   90000
6   140651.75   108000
7   171725.89   126000
8   205503.49   144000
9   242219.73   162000
10  282130.29   180000
11  325513.06   198000")
d <- do.call(rbind,d)
barplot(d , beside=TRUE)
```

Comment: @agstudy I have updated my code with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
mat <- as.matrix(t(d[,2:3]))
colnames(mat) <- d[,1]
barplot(mat , beside=TRUE,legend.text=TRUE,
    args.legend=list(x=8))
```

[image]

Where d is :

```
d <- read.table(text="Year  Balance TotalDeposits
1   18837.44    18000
2   39313.74    36000
3   61571.47    54000
4   85765.63    72000
5   112064.68   90000
6   140651.75   108000
7   171725.89   126000
8   205503.49   144000
9   242219.73   162000
10  282130.29   180000
11  325513.06   198000",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: its working thank you. But can you explain what is the magic in three line code. I am new to R.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want...

```
# after reading in dataframe into d

m <- t(d)
barplot(m[2:3, ] , beside=TRUE, names.arg=m[1, ], 
        col=2:3, las=1, xlab="Year")
legend("topleft", legend=c("Balance", "TotalDeposits"), fill=2:3, box.col=NA)
```

[image]